# How to iteratively run a query on each column in a SQL table with R?

Tags: sql, r, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table with multiple columns (`colA, colB, colC`) and I want to run a query against each of them and store the result so I can use them for comparison purposes later, for example this query to find the ratio of `NULL` and `not NULL` values in a column:

`SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(column), COUNT(column) FROM table;`

I have too many columns to do this manually, so I'm looking for a way for it to cycle through each column and store the result. Using a `WHILE` loop in t-sql doesn't seem to be suitable to this problem, and trying to use for loop with R doesn't work at all:

`tableDataColumnName <- names(tableDataDataframe)`

`for (i in tableDataColumnName){
  nullColumnNumber <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT COUNT (*) - COUNT(i), COUNT(i) FROM dbo.table;")
}`

Is there a way to execute a query multiple times, once for each column in a table, without doing so  manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a variable within a string (the `i`). To do this you should either use `paste` or `paste0` from `base` or something like the `glue` package

```r
## Base 
tableDataColumnName <- names(tableDataDataframe)

for (i in tableDataColumnName){
  nullColumnNumber <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT COUNT (*) - COUNT(", i, "), COUNT(", i, ") FROM dbo.table;"))
}

## Glue
library(glue)
for (i in tableDataColumnName){
  nullColumnNumber <- dbGetQuery(con, glue("SELECT COUNT (*) - COUNT({i}), COUNT({i}) FROM dbo.table;"))
```

However, you're also overwriting the result on each iteration of the loop. My solution for the whole problem would be something like the following:

```r
library(glue)
tableDataColumnName <- names(tableDataDataframe)
nullColumnNumber <- numeric(length(tableDataColumnName))
for (i in seq_along(tableDataColumnName)){
  nullColumnNumber[i] <- dbGetQuery(con, glue("SELECT COUNT (*) - COUNT({tableDataColumnName[i]}), COUNT({tableDataColumnName[i]}) FROM dbo.table;"))
}
```